# Navigation tile text color not changing

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

I have three controller. let's say Controller A, B and C in sequence.

navigation title color in controller A is red.
blue in controller B and green in controller C.

When i push these viewcontroller navigation title color change perfectly. But when coming back to B from C or A from B navigation tile becomes green and blue respectively(sould be blue and red).

What i did: 
I have embedded navigation controller from interface builder in storyboard. To change the title color i used following code in viewWillAppear of every view controller. I placed all my code in main queue. also checked without not placing them in async block and results are same.

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    Dispatch.main.async{
       self.navigationItem.title = "viewcontroller2"
       let textAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue]
       self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes 
    }
}
```

Note that: This problem occur when i use navigation back button to go back but while swipe to back, title color works as it should be. iOS version : 11.4.1. In iOS ver 10.3.3 this issue is not occurring.

Answer (score -1):

Please use like,

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue]
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: Adding layoutIfNeeded() did not result in changing the navigation title foreground color in my tests.